# JavaFx Webview not loading html5 video on localhost server

Tags: java, video, webview, jetty, spark-java

I managed to run simple JavaFx Webview app rendering an html file at a localhost running on micro-services [Spark web framework](http://sparkjava.com/) that uses in embedded jetty container what my issue is the JavaFx Webview is not recognizing the video file source of the html5 video tag while using chrome, ie, and other major browsers the page renders perfectly and the video file is working.

I don't now if it's a bug or is that I have messed something.

here is a working snap of my issue:

**Workspace files lyaout:**

```
Workspace/Work-directory  
  .
    ├── public
    |   └── index.html
    |   └── video.mp4
    └── src
        └── main
        |   └── java
        |       └── com
        |           └── mycompany
        |               └── MainTest.java
        |               └── SparkTest.java
        └── pom.xml
```

**Dependencies(pom.xml):**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

**SparkTest.java**

```
package com.mycompany;

import spark.Spark;

public class SparkTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Spark.staticFiles.externalLocation("public");
        Spark.get("/run", (request, response) -> "Spark is Runnig");
    }
}
```

**MainTest.java**

```
package com.mycompany;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        WebView view = new WebView();
        view.getEngine().load("http://127.0.0.1:4567/index.html");
        root.getChildren().add(view);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>html5 video</h1>
        <video controls preload="auto" width="640" height="480">
            <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

[**here you can find .mp4 video file**](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html)

Comment: I cannot see that you made something wrong; I tried it myself and can confirm: When the page is served by spark, it works with normal browsers but not with JavaFx WebView. But when the page is loaded in the WebView with a local file URI, the video plays. So WebView can play the video, there must be something in the communication between sparkjava /jetty and WebView, but I have not found what it may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After my last comment I debugged and tried a little more and found the following:

The WebView browser tries to load the file from spark by using the *range* http header, to load in chunks; from the spark server logs I can see the following request:

```
GET //127.0.0.1:4567/big_buck_bunny.mp4 
Host: 127.0.0.1:    
X-Playback-Session-Id: 1178DCF3-69C3-4A8E-B5F6-4FD24AD3F421 
Range: bytes=0-1 
Accept: */* 
User-Agent: AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.15G31 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6; de_de) 
Accept-Language: de-de
Accept-Encoding: identity 
Connection: keep-alive
```

Spark at the moment does not support use of the range header for large files, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/257) concerning that missing feature.

So you did not mess something, it's just a missing feature from spark, combined with the fact that WebView does not load the whole file in one piece, I suppose that's because of the data being media served over the net.

Sp your best solution might be looking for a different server to serve your media. Or try to get this feature into spark by either contributing or asking Per Wendel if this could be integrated.

Comment: P.J.Meisch thanks for your support, it's nice that Spark have this in mind.

Answer (score 4):

**As a workaround:**

I used [**jooby**](http://jooby.org/) another micro web framework that uses Netty network applications as a web server, the `<video>` tag work perfectly with JavaFx Webview.

Workspace lyaout and files are the same **except you need to delete** `SparkTest.java` **and edit the pom.xml**

**The dependencies for Jooby/Netty (pom.xml):**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jooby</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooby</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.CR7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jooby</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooby-netty</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.CR7</version>
</dependency>
```

**JoobyTest.java**

```
package com.mycompany;

import org.jooby.Jooby;

public class JoobyTest extends Jooby {
    {
        assets("/**");
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Throwable {
        run(JoobyTest::new, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Jooby/Netty is definitely better than Spark :D